# BitmapFactory.decodeFile is returning null in android

Tags: file, uiimageview, decode, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I want to display the image from my SD card path..I could write and read the image in SD card. I can see the image in sd card saved directory also.But if I give my file path into below line, I am always getting null.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Can u help me ?